# Se puede ingresar un WHERE dentro de un COUNT?

Tags: mysql

Me gustaria saber si se puede añadir este tipo de filtros dentro de un COUNT

Algo asi como `COUNT(nombres WHERE nombres='Ricardo')`

Comment: Agregarías por favor tu consulta completa?

Comment: Posiblemente algo así: `COUNT(CASE WHEN nombres='Ricardo' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho

Comment: @TheImpaler, la idea del NULL es invalidar el COUNT, con 0, estarías contando 1  y no es esa la idea.  En todo caso se podría hacer:  `SUM(CASE WHEN nombres='Ricardo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`